# How to get gcloud.auth.docker-helper out of the habit to hook into non-related docker build?

Tags: docker, gcloud

Sure i have `gcloud` CLI installed. But since when i call `docker build` unrelated to any gcloud actions the log prologs with

```
$ docker build -t ...
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.docker-helper) You do not currently have an active account selected.
Please run:

  $ gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials, or if you have already logged in with a
different account:

  $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT

to select an already authenticated account to use.
Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.346MB
Step 1/8 : FROM node:alpine
...
```

How do i disable gcloud.auth.docker-helper, b/c unrelated, while keeping gcloud installed?

*P.S. Bonus if somebody has pointers/background what this underlying mechanism is and where this behaviour documented on sides of docker and/or gcloud are*

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This appears to be part of [docker login](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credential-helpers) configuration. Specifically the credential helpers specified in the `.docker/config.json`

You can check it by running: `cat [User_Home_Directory]/.docker/config.json`
Example:

```
{
        "auths": {},
        "credHelpers": {
                "asia.gcr.io": "gcr",
                "eu.gcr.io": "gcr",
                "gcr.io": "gcr",
                "marketplace.gcr.io": "gcloud",
                "staging-k8s.gcr.io": "gcr",
                "us.gcr.io": "gcr"
        }
}
```

If you do not want to use anything that requires docker to authenticate with gcloud or gcr (e.g Container Registry), then you can remove the credential helpers from the `.docker/config.json` so it looks like this:

```
{
        "auths": {},
        "credHelpers": {
        }
}
```

For the Docker documentation you can check:

- [docker login](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/)
- [config.json properties](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#configjson-properties)

You can also take a look at [Container Registry Authentication methods](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication) which explains how docker authenticates with gcloud.

Comment: Thanks, this was it. Off topic still disagree that it triggers, docker-compose even exit errors out b/c gcloud. Seems relevant only on docker push, so why does it interfere? Report on gcloud or docker?

Comment: This is something that has to do with Docker. I am not sure if this is intended behavior on Docker side. If it's an issue that's affecting you in any important way, I'd suggest that you contact Docker as they might possibly give you more info on this and any other workarounds than the one I mentioned.